# OpenCV: getLinearRowFilter

Tags: opencv, matrix, row, filtering

I have row kernel

```
cv::Mat kernel = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 3) << -0.5, 0.0, 0.5);
```

And want use it on my matrices like row-wise filter. Before, I'm used filter2D but think that can find 1D filter.
Founded function getLinearRowFilter

```
Ptr<BaseRowFilter> getLinearRowFilter(int srcType, 
                                      int bufType, 
                                      InputArray kernel, 
                                      int anchor, 
                                      int symmetryType)
```

But I can't use resulting BaseRowFilter on my matrix with floating values. Documentation said:

> The class only defines an interface and is not used directly. Instead, there are several functions in OpenCV (and you can add more) that return pointers to the derived classes that implement specific filtering operations. Those pointers are then passed to the FilterEngine constructor. While the filtering operation interface uses the uchar type, a particular implementation is not limited to 8-bit data.

I don't understand that I get implementation of interface, but can applying only uchar rows. Please prompt me, how I can use my BaseRowFilter for row-wise filtering float-matrix (with or without FilterEngine). Thank a lot!

p.s. I want something this:

```
  cv::Ptr<cv::BaseRowFilter> base_row_filter;
  for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i) {
    base_row_filter->operator ()(src.ptr<float>(i),
                                 dst.ptr<float>(i),
                                 src.cols,
                                 1);
  }
```

It is possible?

Comment: Why don't you use `filter2D`? Does it not give you the correct results?

Comment: @beaker I think that filter2D make extra actions, filtering matrix by rows and for each row going for each column, but in 1D filter we set just single row/column, I think that improve performance. filter2D working correctly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reasoning. If your matrix has 2 dimensions, you're going to have to filter over every row. Of course, if your matrix is continuous, it doesn't matter because it's effectively 1 row anyway.

Comment: Yes, but filter kernel is 1D, I thought that row-wise filtering with 1D-filter will be faster than 2D-filter with 1D-kernel on 2D matrix

Comment: I still don't understand your reasoning. The number of calculations is directly dependent on the size of the kernel. Not the number of dimensions of the kernel, the number of elements. If your kernel is `1x9` it's going to do exactly as many calculations as a `3x3` kernel. Look at it this way: If you have a `1x3` kernel, it is going to be applied to *every element in the matrix*. For each element in each row. Calling it a 1D kernel will not reduce that.

Comment: @beaker Thanks! I just want save time on inside checking on row count. I thought its like `for each row in kernel` `do` `for each col in row` `do` `...` in filter2D and something like this `if kernel.rows == 1`  `for each col in kernel.row(0)` `do` `...`